# Jquery Datepicker Days

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have include a jqueryUI Datepicker, I need to change the 2 letters days into 1 letter, example. instead of "Su" for Sunday, it will become "S" for sunday and the rest....
How will I change it???

Comment: Please show what you have tried already.

Comment: none, Ive just applied it the Datepicker Inline

Comment: Then i'd suggest reading the examples and copying them.

Comment: i think you misunderstood it, my point is, on the example it gives a 2 letter i.e."Su" on Sunday.."Mo" on Monday and so on, while I'm trying to point out is to make it a sinlge letter like this "S" on Sunday.."M " on Monday and so on...i'm reading the api documentation but their are no codes that will make it a single letter for days...

Answer (score 20):

I was just wondering this same thing. After looking through the api I found out you can pass an option into the datepicker to change the day names. Here is the api section:
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dayNamesMin

Here is an example:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S']
});
```

Comment: This works - found that the api documentation suggests double quotes - but my instance didn't work as such - switched to single quotes and it worked immediately -

Comment: Thanks man! This worked for me, I was having the same issue. Whereas my issue was I had `dayNames: [ "M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S" ]` but changing it to `dayNamesMin` fixed it. Do you know why `dayNames` wasn't working but `dayNamesMin` did?